# How to set same sequence number on two columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

I am using a sequence in oracle to store incremental value in id column and it is setting on before insert trigger but now I need to store same value in id1 column in same table for some reason.

Please let me know how I can do it.

Comment: In your trigger, you can use `sequence_name.currval` after you have referenced `sequence_name.nextval` -- Oracle 12c has some short-cuts to obtaining `seq.nextval` and `seq.currval` - what version you using?

Comment: I am using oracle12c version.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention a `trigger` I assume you need to know about the [PL/SQL syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS00611).  The important part mentioned in the link is that each time you reference the psuedocolumns `currval` and `nextval` the:

> PL/SQL evaluates every occurrence of sequence_name.CURRVAL and
>   sequence_name.NEXTVAL (unlike SQL, which evaluates a sequence
>   expression for every row in which it appears).

For your purposes, just be careful to just use `nextval` one time in your trigger.

Example of an insert; code for your trigger would be similar.  I was wrong; this syntax was introduced in 11g, so this should work for most people:

```
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO employees_temp (employee_id, dup_id, first_name, last_name)
         VALUES (employees_seq.NEXTVAL, employees_seq.CURRVAL, 'Lynette', 'Smith');

END;
/
```

Note the use of `CURRVAL` in the second `VALUES` parm.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `virtual column` in such case.

Virtual column data is generated on the fly.

```
COL2 NUMBER,
COL3 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS COL2 VIRTUAL
```

In this case `COL3` will be always equal to `COL2`.

If it is really needed to be part of `trigger` then you can simply assign `seq.nextval` to one variable and use that variable for both the columns.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger you should use INSERT...RETURNING syntax. For example,

```
DECLARE
  nID_some_table  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (ID_SOME_TABLE, SOMETHING_ELSE, YA_DA_YA_DA)
    VALUES (SOME_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'bleah-blah-blort', 'ya-da-ya-da-ya-da')
    RETURNING ID_SOME_TABLE INTO nID_some_table;

  -- Now use ID_some_table for some other purpose

  UPDATE SOME_OTHER_TABLE
    SET ID_SOME_TABLE = nID_some_table
    WHERE ID_SOME_OTHER_TABLE = nHeaven_only_knows;
END;
```